# is this usage of “later” natural?

Tags: adverbs, future-constructions

I’d like to know if it’s natural/grammatically correct to use “later” with the future tense.

> I’ll call you a week later.

Comment: It's correct and natural, and it means, "I'll call you a week *after that*." It's not clear what "that" is.

Answer (score 1):

"Later" is a *comparative* term, like 'hotter', 'darker', etc.

When we say "I'll call you later", it means at some point *later than now*. But if you bring a specific time into it as in your example of "a week", it doesn't make any sense unless you give a starting point to count that week from.

For example, you could say "I'll call you a week later *than originally promised*" because there is something to compare it to - you must have previously said you'd call on one date, and now you're calling a week later than that. Without a comparison though, it would not make sense.

If you just mean to say that you will call a week *from now*, idiomatic ways to say that would include:

- I'll call you in a week's time
- I'll call you in a week
- I'll call you a week from today

Answer (score 0):

Not really. I'd say something like "I'll call you in a week" or "I'll call you later".